# String theory coset-space theories in the text book by Becker, Becker and Schwarz (BBS)

Tags: string-theory, lie-algebra, affine-lie-algebra

I am reading the *string theory and M-theory* by Becker, Becker and Schwarz (BBS). And I came across a section in chapter 3 called coset-space theories (after equation 3.58)

At the beginning of this section, the author mentions that

> "Suppose that the Kac-Moody algebra $\hat{G}_k$ has a subalgebra $\hat{H_l}$, the level $l$ is determined by the embedding of $H$ in $G$. For example, if the simple roots of $H$ are a subset of the simple roots of $G$, then $l=k$. If the Kac-Moody algebra is a direct product of the form $\hat{G}_{k1}\times \hat{G}_{k2}$, and $\hat{H}_l$ is the diagonal subgroup, then $l=k_1+k_2$"

I actually have no clue what this paragraph is talking about. Can anyone give a more detailed illustration of this paragraph? For example, I don't understand the statement that when the simple roots of $H$ is a subset of the simple roots of $G$, then $l=k$, how to prove this? And also what does that diagonal subgroup mean? Is $\hat{G_{k1}}\times \hat{G_{k2}}$ referring to the direct product of two copies of the algebra of the same Lie group $G$, but with different level $k_1$ and $k_2$?

Also, at the end of the section, the author also gives in equation 3.69, as a specific example,
$$\frac{\hat{SU}(2)_k\times \hat{SU}(2)_{l}}{\hat{SU}(2)_{k+l}}$$

> where the diagonal embedding is understood

What is this diagonal embedding referring to, and where does this $\hat{SU}(2)_{k+l}$ come from?

Comment: You may want to check a good Conformal Field Theory book, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Conformal-Theory-Graduate-Contemporary-Physics/dp/1461274753